# Is there a way to cast to an Int from a diff on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, timestamp

I have a function `fn_weekly` that produces exactly what I want `1` if week has changed (on Mondays).  `df` is any dataframe with timestamps for an index.

I'm trying to create a `fn_monthly` that outputs the same format, but I'm getting **floats** instead of **ints**.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Also, if there's a cleaner way to implement `fn_monthly`, do let me know.  Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd

fn_weekly = lambda df: pd.DataFrame(df.index.isocalendar().week).diff()

fn_monthly = lambda df: pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(df.index.month, index=df.index)).diff()

>>> fn_weekly(df)
            week
Date
2019-02-04  <NA>
2019-02-05     0
2019-02-06     0
2019-02-07     0
2019-02-08     0
...          ...
2021-02-01     1
2021-02-02     0
2021-02-03     0
2021-02-04     0
2021-02-05     0

>>> fn_monthly(df)
            Date
Date
2019-02-04   NaN
2019-02-05   0.0
2019-02-06   0.0
2019-02-07   0.0
2019-02-08   0.0
...          ...
2021-02-01   1.0
2021-02-02   0.0
2021-02-03   0.0
2021-02-04   0.0
2021-02-05   0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the easy way you can change the value to int with:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(int)
```

Also, to avoid problems with NaN values, you can try the fillna function

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Now as for the difference in the type of values, when looking over the documentation of the diff function of pandas Series (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) It says the following on the notes section:

```
Notes

For boolean dtypes, this uses operator.xor() rather than operator.sub(). 
The result is calculated according to current dtype in Series, however dtype 
of the result is always float64.
```

The result of a series.diff is always float, that is why you have a difference in the types of values

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  However, this technique doesn't appear to like the first row which contains a 'NaN' (as opposed to a '<NA>') in the first one.  I get a 'ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer'.

Comment: Also, oddly, when I check on the element types in using the fn_weekly lambda, I get '<class 'numpy.uint32'>' (counter to your documentation reference) - makes me go hmm...

Comment: fn_monthly is different from fn_weekly because in your code you transform it to a series in pd.Series(df.index.month, index=df.index)), that's why you get a different data type

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

In your example `week` column has [nullable integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) type (`Int` or `UInt` dtype, notice capital `I` in type name).

`month` column has a regular integer type (`int` - default).

## Example

```py
>>> pd.Series([0, 1, 1]).diff()
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    0.0
dtype: float64
```

- `diff()` operation *ruins* an `int` column type (`int` → `float64`), because `int` type cannot hold NaN value.

```py
>>> pd.Series([0, 1, 1], dtype='UInt8').diff()
0    <NA>
1       1
2       0
dtype: UInt8
```

- In this case the type `UInt8` is preserved after `diff()` operation.

Docs [states](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

> The result is calculated according to current dtype in Series, however dtype of the result is always float64.

But it's seems that it's **not true** in case of nullable integer type.